# Async IO at random offsets

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, asynchronous

We have a 20 GB file from which we want to read data at random offsets, so it is not sequential read. I am planning to use asynchronous IO, however I am noticing this limitation –

my requirement, as I said, is to read at random offsets. However the BeginRead API does not take an offset into the file, it only takes an offset into the buffer it is reading to
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxt5ahzw)

So my only option is to use FileStream.Seek . However, the problem with that is if I am using async IO

FileStream fs = Foo.txt is used by both threads

```
Thread 1                               Thread 2

fs.Seek(offset1)                       
(Thread 1 gets preempted)              
                                       fs.Seek(offset2)        
                                       fs.BeginRead
fs.BeginRead
```

As you can see if Thread 1 gets preempted just after Seek to offset 1, then Thread 1 will end up reading from offset2 which was not the intention.

Does this mean I have to use a lock? That would defeat the purpose of async IO.

Comment: From your pseudocode, it looks like you have separate file streams opened on the same file.  Seeking in one file stream is not going to affect the other one.  Who is the "you" in "your class", by the way?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the different filestream issue, I corrected it. Since this is asynchronous IO only one filestream is getting used. Otherwise there will be too many filestreams folating around in the server.

(the class thingy was a copy paste typo :) )

Comment: It seems like the same `FileStream` in both threads. That's always going to be a problem.

Comment: @Prapti why do you think that async IO requires you to share filestreams between threads?  It does not.

Comment: I am actually worried about the large number of filestream objects. Each filestream object requires kernel resources. I know async IO does not require it. 
It is a WCF server app which is processing requests on their own threads. There may be thousands of filestream objects then

Comment: If you ave thousands of simultaneous threads, you might be in trouble.  That is as worrisome as thousands of file handles.

Comment: How about managing a pool of FileStream objects?

Comment: @Prapti perhaps you should persist your data in a database rather than in a file.  A good database system will handle all of that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all clear if this applies to your situation, but give [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) a look, it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Each file stream will have its own offset, so this should just work - see the example below (completely synchronous).

```
public class StackOverflow_10543252
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        byte[] bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
        File.WriteAllBytes("a.bin", bytes);
        FileStream fs1 = File.OpenRead("a.bin");
        fs1.Seek(40, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        FileStream fs2 = File.OpenRead("a.bin");
        fs2.Seek(120, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Console.WriteLine(fs1.ReadByte()); // should be 40
        Console.WriteLine(fs2.ReadByte()); // should be 120
        fs1.Close();
        fs2.Close();
        File.Delete("a.bin");
    }
}
```

**Update**: saw the edit after posted this answer. If you need to have only 1 `FileStream` pointer (which may or may not be required), then you'll need to use some locking to prevent the two concurrent operations from overlapping each other. But if you can use multiple FileStream pointers, then your life will be easier.

By the way, you can do non-sequential reads with synchronous calls - it doesn't have to be asynchronous for that (the example above did just that). Adding asynchronous operations usually comes up with an additional complexity, so you should see if it's really required.

Comment: Thanks Carlos for your answer. It is a WCF server app which is processing requests on their own threads. Is it advisable to create separate filestream for each thread? There may be thousands of filestream objects then.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the threads to wait for one another, then **you will need one Stream per thread**, even if these accesses happen asynchronously.

Now if your threads spend most of their time doing other things, then **you could open the stream on demand and close it after you're done**. Streams wrap native resources, file handles, so you certainly shouldn't have hundreds of them lying around, doing nothing.

The last option would be to **manage a pool of open streams**. Whenever a thread needs to read from the file, hand out one of the streams to the thread. After it is done, the stream should be returned to the pool for use by other threads. You will of course have to **synchronize access to the pool**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Sharing File access options for your reads.

If you don't need read/write sharing and it's just reading, you can reduce the FileAccess/FileShare properties.

```
Using f As FileStream = mTransferFile.Open(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    Dim newPosition As Long = t.ID * mTransferInfo.BlockSize
    f.Position = newPosition

    'Do stuff here. Open another filestream etc.

End Using
```